# Regex to match repeating groups in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a countries.txt file that contains the following sample text:

```
[Country "Kenya"]\n[CapitalCity "Nairobi"]\n\n
[Country "Uganda"]\n[CapitalCity "Kampala"]\n\n
[Country "Tanzania"]\n[CapitalCity "Dodoma"]\n\n
```

The country can have up to 20 attributes. For simplicity, i have only included Country and CapitalCity.
I need a regex that works in python that will return for the sample data above:

```
a) n matches, in the above case n=3
b) Each match should have m groups, in this case m=2: Country and CapitalCity
```

I have read this https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html but cannot seem to get it to work for my usecase.

I have tried this

```
(\[([A-Za-z]+)\s\"([^\"]*)\"\]\\n\\n)+
```

here https://regex101.com/r/cujIDd/1 but it does not give me the Country.

**EDIT**:
Expected input and output

Example 1:
input

```
[Country "Kenya"]\n[CapitalCity "Nairobi"]\n\n
[Country "Uganda"]\n[CapitalCity "Kampala"]\n\n
[Country "Tanzania"]\n[CapitalCity "Dodoma"]\n\n
```

expected output

```
matches: 3
match 1: Country: Kenya
         CapitalCity: Nairobi
match 2: Country: Uganda
         CapitalCity: Kampala
match 3: Country: Tanzania
         CapitalCity: Dodoma
```

Example 2:
input

```
[Country "Kenya"]\n[CapitalCity "Nairobi"]\n[President "Kenyatta"]\n\n
[Country "Uganda"]\n[CapitalCity "Kampala"]\n[President "Museveni"]\n\n
[Country "Tanzania"]\n[CapitalCity "Dodoma"]\n[President "Magufuli"]\n\n
```

expected output

```
matches: 3
match 1: Country: Kenya
         CapitalCity: Nairobi
         President: Kenyatta
match 2: Country: Uganda
         CapitalCity: Kampala
         President: Museveni
match 3: Country: Tanzania
         CapitalCity: Dodoma
         President: Magufuli
```

Example 3:
input

```
[Country "Kenya"]\n[CapitalCity "Nairobi"]\n[President "Kenyatta"]\n[Continent "Africa"]\n\n
[Country "Uganda"]\n[CapitalCity "Kampala"]\n[President "Museveni"]\n[Continent "Africa"]\n\n
[Country "Tanzania"]\n[CapitalCity "Dodoma"]\n[President "Magufuli"]\n[Continent "Africa"]\n\n
```

expected output

```
matches: 3
match 1: Country: Kenya
         CapitalCity: Nairobi
         President: Kenyatta
         Continent: Africa
match 2: Country: Uganda
         CapitalCity: Kampala
         President: Museveni
         Continent: Africa
match 3: Country: Tanzania
         CapitalCity: Dodoma
         President: Magufuli
         Continent: Africa
```

You get the flow

Comment: you've included double `\n` in your capture group. [correction](https://regex101.com/r/cujIDd/2)

Comment: Thanks @OmarEinea. However that gives me 6 matches.

Comment: 1) can you explain what `n matches` mean here? 2) does your input file literally contains the string `\n`? 3) added complete expected output to question, it will give better understanding of your question

Comment: @Sundeep
1) n is number of countries. in this case 3
2) Yes it does

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use something similar to the following:

```
regex = r"^[^\"]*\"(\w+)\"[^\"]+\"(\w+)\"[^\"].*"
subst = "\\1, \\2"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

**Output**:

```
Kenya, Nairobi
Uganda, Kampala
Tanzania, Dodoma
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/cujIDd/6

Comment: Thanks @l'L'l . However that would not satisfy the requirement for this input text:
    
    [Country "Kenya"]\n[Capital "Nairobi"]\n[President "Kenyatta"]\n\n
    [Country "Uganda"]\n[Capital "Kampala"]\n[President "Museveni"]\n\n
    [Country "Tanzania"]\n[Capital "Dodoma"]\n[President "Magufuli"]\n\n

Remember these attributes can be up to 20.

Comment: @usr2564301 The question indicates that the number of attributes can be up to 20. In the answer provided, only 2 have been captured. Which means if the number of attributes are 20, it will not work

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the outer repeating group `()+` and make the second `\\n` optional `(?:\\n)?`:

See the [regex in use](https://regex101.com/r/0VoFkr/1) on regex101.com

`\[([A-Za-z]+)\s\"([^\"]*)\"\]\\n(?:\\n)?`

If you want to capture only the first 2 attributes, you could use `^` and `$` anchors:

`^\[([A-Za-z]+)\s*\"([^\"]+)\"\]\\n\[([A-Za-z]+)\s*\"([^\"]+)\"\].*$`

See the [regex in use](https://regex101.com/r/0VoFkr/3) on regex101.com

Comment: @Telewa I have updated my answer and separated the link and the regex

Comment: Thanks.
Can it have only 3 matches - those are only 3 countries?

Comment: I took those from your example data. Not sure what you mean, but I think you can add as many as you want. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/0VoFkr/2)

Comment: what i mean is, Per match, all attributes should be captured. So for the example i provided, there should be 3 matches, and two attribures captured. If we add the number of attributes and keep the countries as they are, we  should still have 3 matches, and the extra attributes per match captured as well

Comment: Yes! Absolutely! Now it only didn't match attribute "President" in the second data. All attributes should be captured. Those attributes can be between 1 and m

Comment: @Telewa Ok nice! I have added that to my answer.

Comment: Field President is not yet captured. I want to capture all attributes.

Comment: The first regex captures all the attributes, the second regex captures the first and the second as in the Country and the CapitalCity. If you want to capture the first 3, you can extend the matches [in the regex](https://regex101.com/r/0VoFkr/5) and make the last one optional.

Comment: That is amazing. I was just hoping i would't have to keep extending the regex 20 times to match the 20 attributes. This is the closest though we have got. (the second).

Comment: That is what is already does.  [Example](https://regex101.com/r/0VoFkr/6)

Comment: In that link, [Capital "Dodoma"] is match on its own rather than an attribute under [Country "Tanzania"]\n`
Also, please see my edits to the question to clarify the examples.